# How to Grab value from ancestors in MySQL where child element is null recursively using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, parent-child, traversal

I am not sure if this makes sense entirely the way I have this worded but here we go:
I am trying to figure out how to create a recursive loop in php that basically checks if a child column is null - if that child elements column has a null value then it recursively goes through its ancestors using parent id's until it finds a parent that has a value for that column and then that parents value is put into the original child's column. I am absolutely stumped on this as I am just starting out using php but I have a solid understanding of databases and mysql. Any help and code examples would be awesome.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you describing a table with the columns ParentID, ChildID, and TheThingIWant? And you want to select TheThingIWant, or if TheThingIWant is null, select TheThingIWant from the nearest ancestor?

Comment: Yes that is basically what I am trying to achieve. Sorry if the wording was a little confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A warning about using the Adjacency List model to store hierarchical data: it trades ease of creating and updating the table for a lack of efficiency in getting data back out again.  I personally used [Closure Tables](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/02/14/moving-subtrees-in-closure-table/) in my project because, even though it was crazy figuring out how to get the data in there and how to update them, it was far more efficient at getting the data back out again.  If you had Closure Tables, you could use one query to get the list of all the parents of your node that have information, and use ORDER BY Distance LIMIT 1 to get just the parent you want for your answer.  Using [Nested Sets](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) could also be an option, although I know less about them.  You should look into those and consider your options before continuing.

This is for the Adjacency List that you have now:

```
$target = 4; //whatever ID
$db = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT ParentID, Audience FROM things WHERE ChildID = ?");

$audience = NULL;
$ChildID = $target; // starts as same value
while(!isset($audience) || !isset($ChildID)) {  //This assumes that the top ParentID is null; you might have to adjust it
     $statement->bind_param('i', $ChildID);
     $statement->execute();
     $result = $statement->get_result();
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
         if(!isset($row['Audience']) && !isset($audience)) {
             $ChildID = isset($row['ParentID'])?$row['ParentID']:NULL;
         } else {
             $audience = $row['Audience'];
         }
     }
     $result->free();
}

if(isset($audience)) {
    if($target == $ChildID) { //it was found on that first try
         echo $audience.' was found for '.$target;
    } else {
        $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE things SET Audience = ? WHERE ChildID = ?");
        $statement->bind_param('si', $audience, $target); 
        $statement->execute();
        echo $audience.' was set for '.$target;
    }
} else {
    echo 'No audience was found or set for '.$target;
}


$db->close();
```

Note that the first parameter of bind_param cares what type your binding things are (string, integer, decimal, blob).  You might have to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

please provide the example tables/fields.  we couldn't tell if you meant 1 table or several.

your php code could look something like this (query stuff is pseudocode)

```
function updateChild($ChildID,$ParentID=-1)
{
    //use mysqlquery or whatever
    if($ParentID==-1)
       select field_value,parent_id from mytable where rowid=$ChildID; 
    else
       select field_value,parent_id from mytable where parentid=$ParentID;
    $candidate_value=$row['field_value'];
    $fallback_parent=$row['parent_id']

    if (  is_null($candidate_value))
        updateChild($ChildID, $fallback_parent)
    else
        update mytable set field_value=$candidate_value where $ChildID=$ChildID   
}
```

The thought is that you start by grabbing the current field value, and the parentID just in case.  if it turns out to be null,  you call the same function again, passing in the child or rowid and the next parent to check.  if a parent turns out to be OK, the it updates using  the child value that has been passed all along.  Note, the code above will update the child value with "itself" if it does indeed have a value on the first try, so that should probably be fixed by checking if the parentid is -1.

Comment: It would be one table that we are navigating through. Assume that you have a column called "audience" that can be null, and we are basically trying to fill this column with a value from a parent or an ancestor, but we only want to fill that "audience" column for the child if the parent or ancestor has an actual value for "audience" - which is why I have to have recursive code.

Comment: *We also don't want to fill the child "audience" column if it actually has a value